# Automated building equinox PDE : executable doesn't work

Tags: macos, export, osgi, eclipse-pde, p2

I created an OSGi project in which one I've 2 projects :
- one plugin project : that contains my source files, my product configuration that uses my feature project and the feature org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.user. It means that my program is able to install new software or to update the program.
- one feature project that contains my plugin project.

I can run my program into eclipse, It works. I can export my product configuration from eclipse and then launching my program : it works.

After that, I'd like to build automaticaly my program with the framework PDE of eclipse. I followed this tutorial : http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse. pde.doc.user/guide/tasks/pde_product_build.htm . I'm able to generate my program for Windows,Linux and Mac os. The executables of windows and linux work. However, the executable of mac os doesn't work.

When I click on the icon, nothing happens and I've no error. To be able to launch on mac os, I've to replace the file myExecutable.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse by the one of Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse. It seams that the file "eclipse" of my generated executable is not in the right format.

Do you know what is the reason of this problem? Or maybe if you have a clue for me to solve that.

Thank you very much,

Bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click on myExecutable.app and select 'Show Package Contents', you can drill in to find the actual executable.  You can run this from a shell prompt and see any error output.  You can also find the logs in the structure hidden inside the .app.

I'd recommending comparing the eclipse.ini files for your executable app and the one from Eclipse that is working for you.  There may be a option that you are missing that you can add to your .product Mac OS X specific options.

Comment: It was only : chmod 755 eclipse

Comment: @user376112, your own cross-post at http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=543640& has more interesting info than that posted here, notably that this was a bug in setting permissions on Macs in pre-Helios builds of eclipse, and that there is a workaround to change the archive file format to zip which eclipse will set with the correct permissions.